# How can I determine the best mathematical model in a Pythonian way?

Tags: python

I have four mathematical models and I want to select the best one on a given dataset. The selection criterion is MSE, which has to be minimum.

To select the best model, I can store each model's MSE in a list, determine the minimum MSE and, through a series of `if`, `elif` and `else` get my answer. This is the intuitive way, but it gets really tiresome if I want to add more models.

Is there a better, more Pythonic way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Python has a built-in `min` function to determine the minimum of any amount of numbers/model scores/etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store models *alongside* their scores in a dictionary:

```
results = {model1: 0.4654, model2: 0.78, model3: 0.93}
```

Then choose the model with the lowest score:

```
min(results.items(), key=lambda model_and_score: model_and_score[1])
```

This will return a tuple `(best_model, best_score)`.

Comment: Or `min(results, key=results.get)` which will return just the model